# Failed loading from file in class constructor issue

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to add the option in class A constructor to load objects from file. But I'm not sure what to do when loading fails (file loading fails, bad file format ..). Code uses A whether loadObjects is true or not which leads to segmentation fault. Maybe loading in constructor isn't the best approach ...

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        A(const std::vector<Obj<T>*>& o) : objs(o) {}

        A(const std::string& file)
        {
            // loadObject adds new objects in objs
            // objs.push_back(new Obj<T>);
            if ( loadObjects(file, objs) ) 
            {
                // good, can use object A
            }
            else
            {
                // Segmentation fault when using undefined A, 
                // What can I do to stop execution here.
            }

        }

        virtual ~A()
        {
            for (size_t i=0; i<objs.size(); ++i)
                delete objs[i];
            objs.clear();
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Obj<T>*> objs;

};
```

Comment: Maybe just output an error message and exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `throw`. Object will not be created in this case and you can catch exception on the other level.

Comment: I have no idea how to catch execption, will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function initialize() in which you can load a file, and then have it called in the A's constructor function. Besides, before using class A's object, validate this object. So in this case, operation afterwards won't continue.

```
    A::A(const std::string& file)
    {
        if (initialize(const std::string& file) == SUCCESS)
            ....
        else
            ....
    }

    void A::initialize(const std::string& file)
    {
        if ( loadObjects(file, objs) ) 
        {
            // good, can use object A
        }
        else
        {
            // Segmentation fault when using undefined A, 
            // What can I do to stop execution here.
        }
    }
```

Then when use A's object.

```
    A obj("abc.txt");

    if (obj is valid)
        do something;
    else
        return;
```